Generating all sequences and probabilities for a random process in R
I have a Markov Chain in R:
set.seed(123)

n_states <- 5

matrix <- matrix(runif(n_states^2), nrow=n_states)

# set some transitions to 0 
matrix[1, 4:5] <- 0 
matrix[5, 1:3] <- 0  
matrix[2, 5] <- 0    

transition_matrix <- t(apply(matrix, 1, function(x) x/sum(x)))

rownames(transition_matrix) <- paste0("S", 1:n_states)
colnames(transition_matrix) <- paste0("S", 1:n_states)

print(round(transition_matrix, 3))

It looks like this:
          S1         S2        S3         S4        S5
S1 0.2229340 0.03531601 0.7417500 0.00000000 0.0000000
S2 0.3910569 0.26197885 0.2248868 0.12207747 0.0000000
S3 0.1536622 0.33530265 0.2545791 0.01580275 0.2406533
S4 0.2652280 0.16563210 0.1719994 0.09849610 0.2986444
S5 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.59278229 0.4072177

For a fixed number of turns, I want to find out all possible state sequences that can occur and their corresponding probabilities.
I tried to do this manually using loops to enumerate all such sequences:
# Function to generate sequences for multiple turn lengths
find_sequences_all_turns <- function(transition_matrix, start_state = 1, max_turns = 5) {
    n_states <- nrow(transition_matrix)
    
   
    all_sequences <- list()
    all_probabilities <- numeric()
    all_turns <- numeric()
    seq_counter <- 1
    
    generate_sequence <- function(current_seq, current_prob, steps_left, total_steps) {
        if(length(current_seq) > 1) {
            all_sequences[[seq_counter]] <<- current_seq
            all_probabilities[seq_counter] <<- current_prob
            all_turns[seq_counter] <<- total_steps - steps_left
            seq_counter <<- seq_counter + 1
        }
        
        if(steps_left == 0) {
            return()
        }
        
        current_state <- current_seq[length(current_seq)]
        possible_next_states <- which(transition_matrix[current_state,] > 0)
        
        for(next_state in possible_next_states) {
            prob <- transition_matrix[current_state, next_state]
            generate_sequence(
                c(current_seq, next_state),
                current_prob * prob,
                steps_left - 1,
                total_steps
            )
        }
    }
    
    generate_sequence(c(start_state), 1, max_turns - 1, max_turns)
    
    result_df <- data.frame(
        turn = all_turns,
        sequence_no = 1:length(all_sequences),
        sequence = sapply(all_sequences, paste, collapse=""),
        probability = all_probabilities
    )
    
    result_df <- result_df[order(result_df$turn, -result_df$probability),]
    rownames(result_df) <- NULL
    
    return(result_df)
}

I then tried to call the function:
sequences_df <- find_sequences_all_turns(transition_matrix)

> sequences_df
    turn sequence_no sequence  probability
1      2         154       13 7.417500e-01
2      2           1       11 2.229340e-01
3      2          65       12 3.531601e-02
4      3         171      132 2.487108e-01
5      3         193      133 1.888341e-01
6      3         243      135 1.785046e-01
7      3          40      113 1.653613e-01
8      3         155      131 1.139789e-01
9      3           2      111 4.969955e-02
10     3          66      121 1.381057e-02
11     3         218      134 1.172169e-02
12     3          82      122 9.252048e-03
13     3         104      123 7.942105e-03
14     3          18      112 7.873137e-03
15     3         129      124 4.311289e-03

Is there something I can do to make sure this code run faster for large number of turns

PS: I used this code to verify all probabilities sum to 1 for each turn:
library(dplyr)

probability_sums <- sequences_df %>%
    group_by(turn) %>%
    summarise(
        total_probability = sum(probability),
        num_sequences = n(),
        check_sum_to_one = abs(total_probability - 1) < 1e-10
    )

print(probability_sums)


I think it should work well for your purpose (given tm <- transition_matrix, shorter variable name for "transition matrix")
nms <- row.names(tm)
N <- 5
res <-lapply(2:N, function(k) {
    u <- expand.grid(rep(list(nms), k))
    subset(
        transform(
            u,
            Freq = Reduce(`*`, Map(\(x, y) tm[cbind(x, y)], u[-length(u)], u[-1]))
        ),
        Freq > 0
    )
})

and you can see
> lapply(res, head, n = 10)
[[1]]
   Var1 Var2       Freq
1    S1   S1 0.22293395
2    S2   S1 0.39105686
3    S3   S1 0.15366217
4    S4   S1 0.26522803
6    S1   S2 0.03531601
7    S2   S2 0.26197885
8    S3   S2 0.33530265
9    S4   S2 0.16563210
11   S1   S3 0.74175004
12   S2   S3 0.22488682

[[2]]
   Var1 Var2 Var3       Freq
1    S1   S1   S1 0.04969955
2    S2   S1   S1 0.08717985
3    S3   S1   S1 0.03425651
4    S4   S1   S1 0.05912833
6    S1   S2   S1 0.01381057
7    S2   S2   S1 0.10244863
8    S3   S2   S1 0.13112240
9    S4   S2   S1 0.06477157
11   S1   S3   S1 0.11397892
12   S2   S3   S1 0.03455660

[[3]]
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4        Freq
1    S1   S1   S1   S1 0.011079716
2    S2   S1   S1   S1 0.019435348
3    S3   S1   S1   S1 0.007636940
4    S4   S1   S1   S1 0.013181713
6    S1   S2   S1   S1 0.003078844
7    S2   S2   S1   S1 0.022839277
8    S3   S2   S1   S1 0.029231635
9    S4   S2   S1   S1 0.014439781
11   S1   S3   S1   S1 0.025409771
12   S2   S3   S1   S1 0.007703838

[[4]]
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5         Freq
1    S1   S1   S1   S1   S1 0.0024700449
2    S2   S1   S1   S1   S1 0.0043327990
3    S3   S1   S1   S1   S1 0.0017025332
4    S4   S1   S1   S1   S1 0.0029386513
6    S1   S2   S1   S1   S1 0.0006863789
7    S2   S2   S1   S1   S1 0.0050916503
8    S3   S2   S1   S1   S1 0.0065167238
9    S4   S2   S1   S1   S1 0.0032191175
11   S1   S3   S1   S1   S1 0.0056647005
12   S2   S3   S1   S1   S1 0.0017174471


Another option (might be more efficient since the rows that result in 0 probabilities are filtered out in advances) is using merge within a repeat loop, to update the table, iteratively
N <- 5
dp <- d <- subset(as.data.frame.table(tm), Freq > 0)
res <- list(dp)
repeat {
    if (length(res) == N - 1) break
    p <- names(dp[-length(dp)])
    q <- paste0("Var", as.integer(sub("\\D+", "", p)) + 1)
    dnew <- setNames(dp, c(q, "yFreq"))
    dp <- subset(
        transform(
            merge(d, dnew)[unique(c(p, names(dnew), "Freq"))],
            Freq = Freq * yFreq
        ),
        select = -yFreq
    )
    res[[length(res) + 1]] <- dp
}

such that
> lapply(res, head, n = 10)
[[1]]
   Var1 Var2       Freq
1    S1   S1 0.22293395
2    S2   S1 0.39105686
3    S3   S1 0.15366217
4    S4   S1 0.26522803
6    S1   S2 0.03531601
7    S2   S2 0.26197885
8    S3   S2 0.33530265
9    S4   S2 0.16563210
11   S1   S3 0.74175004
12   S2   S3 0.22488682

[[2]]
   Var1 Var2 Var3        Freq
1    S1   S1   S1 0.049699546
2    S1   S1   S2 0.007873137
3    S1   S1   S3 0.165361267
4    S2   S1   S1 0.087179851
5    S2   S1   S2 0.013810568
6    S2   S1   S3 0.290066443
7    S3   S1   S1 0.034256514
8    S3   S1   S2 0.005426735
9    S3   S1   S3 0.113978919
10   S4   S1   S1 0.059128333

[[3]]
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4         Freq
1    S1   S1   S1   S1 0.0110797161
2    S1   S1   S1   S2 0.0017551896
3    S1   S1   S1   S3 0.0368646403
4    S1   S1   S3   S2 0.0554460705
5    S1   S1   S3   S3 0.0420975207
6    S1   S1   S3   S4 0.0026131624
7    S1   S1   S3   S5 0.0397947423
8    S1   S1   S2   S4 0.0009611327
9    S1   S1   S2   S1 0.0030788444
10   S1   S1   S2   S2 0.0020625955

[[4]]
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5         Freq
1    S1   S1   S1   S1   S1 0.0024700449
2    S1   S1   S1   S1   S2 0.0003912914
3    S1   S1   S1   S1   S3 0.0082183799
4    S1   S1   S1   S3   S2 0.0123608115
5    S1   S1   S1   S3   S3 0.0093849666
6    S1   S1   S1   S3   S4 0.0005825626
7    S1   S1   S1   S3   S5 0.0088715991
8    S1   S1   S1   S2   S4 0.0002142691
9    S1   S1   S1   S2   S1 0.0006863789
10   S1   S1   S1   S2   S2 0.0004598226

